# regex look ahead operator

Tags: regex, string, split

I have a string consisting of N- length of special character delimiters, 
Input: `--1-----3--1-2` where once the .split method applied on the pattern should give output as below.

I wish to make a pattern where if the length of delimiter,N is N>1, to get the resulting match as,
Output: `1,3,1,-2`

Note the last element.

So far I have implemented the use of look ahead operator:
`(\W)(?=[\-{2,}\d])` giving `1,3,1,2`.

Any feedback is appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: What's the language? You could split on `-{2,}|(?=-)`? [Illustrated here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aYEaMk/1).

Comment: Thanks  @ClasG .

Answer (score 0):

How about: `(\W){2,}`

That will give you `131-2` on your input.

https://regex101.com/r/algIJ7/1

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works on the example I have given but breaks down on a general case where delimiters lie within the integer sequence  e.g: ---2-2--2 -> 2,2 but I need another negative digit.

Comment: Based on the answers given to me I have figured this would work for  delimiters of length N >2 and at the same time retain the negative values. (\W){2,}|(?=\W)